# monitoring remote windows machines (CPU%, RAM, Process, restart) in python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, python-2.7, remote-access

I'm trying to build a monitoring program for our eight render machines (incl. refresh every second). Displaying the current status will be made with the use of Tkinter which is working great so far, but I can't figure out how to connect to the remote machines.

I've tried...

- WMI (runs, but not as a thread so I can check every machine simultaneously)
- psutil (only local stats)
- Popen (can't remember why that didn't work - been fighting with this application for quite a while now, sorry)
- glances (same here - and I think because it's more of a stand-alone program and needs to be installed together with a webserver on all the render machines? Really not sure on that one though!)

I'm starting to lose my mind here and maybe someone can give me a hint in the right direction?

Thanks!

---

Just as a additional info - what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Display icon if machine is running (this works - Yay!)
2. Display CPU% of process A
3. Display CPU% of process B
4. System CPU%
5. Free RAM
6. Restart process A
7. Restart process B
8. Restart machine
9. View last screenshot taken

Thanks again! Any help is appreciated. I quess this isn't the ideal project for a novice programer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using SaltStack. You can set up the [salt minion](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/installation/windows.html) on a windows machine, and then use it to get [information about the minion](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.status.html). You can also run commands on the minions, to restart applications, etc.